# How to stop different combinations of words

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net Mvc4 and I am successfully using RegularExpression to block bad words but my issue is that if someone puts those bad words in uppercase then it goes through, how can I stop that?
This is what I have

```
[RegularExpression("^((?!(www|gamble|keygen|http)).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid word")]
```

So if someone puts **www** it would stop it but if they put **Www WWW wwW** it would go through; is there anything that I can do to stop all combinations of a word ?

Comment: Use the `i` flag. It ignores case.

Comment: If someone wants to convey something through text, they will, no matter how many restrictions you put into place.

Comment: Just don't go there. As great as Regexs are they are easily fooled by dedicated posters.

Comment: @AmalMurali: You are right, however restrictions may discourage some people (and eventually an important percentage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're not using this to do client-side validation (I think you don't want to actually send the list of bad words to the client, do you?).

In this case, you can use the `i` modifier by prepending `(?i)` to the regular expression, as `RegularExpressionAttribute` doesn't support externally supplied modifiers. Please note that this doesn't work in JavaScript (as it doesn't support inline modifiers).

But, as others have pointed out, such kind of protection can be easily fooled, and worse, you could block legitimate requests, so be careful with that. You should for instance use `\b` anchors to limit yourself to whole words, that'll avoid a lot of unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for that I will be careful with it and it worked.